# Form in React w/ different input types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a React form that collects answer submissions in a Google spreadsheet. I started out based on a tutorial, and it works as long as I only have only text input. However, I also want to add one question with answer selections, and that's where I start to fail. I'm super new to React, so I understand the problem (sort of), but I'm clueless as to how to fix it, i.e., how to integrate both parts.

So, here's what I have (url redacted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Form, Container, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
       name: '',
       email: '',
    }
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value})
  }

  submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

    axios.post('url', this.state)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { name, email} = this.state; 
    return (
      <Container fluid className="container">
        <Header as='h2'>Activity Sign-Up</Header>
        <Form className="form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Name | Nombre</label>
            <input placeholder='Name / Nombre' type="text" name = "name" value = {name} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Email | Correo electrónico</label>
            <input placeholder='Email / Correo electrónico' type="email" name = "email" value = {email} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          </Form.Field>

          <Button color="blue" type='submit'>Submit | Enviar</Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

And here's a snippet of what I'd like to integrate. (I know how to put this together on its own, but not as part of the above.)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const PARTICIPATION = [
  "Yes, I would like to participate in this activity.",
  "Sí, me gustaría participar en esta actividad.",
  ""
];

function RegisterForActivitiesForm() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    participation: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const set = (name) => {
    return ({ target: { value } }) => {
      setValues((oldValues) => ({ ...oldValues, [name]: value }));
    };
  };

//...

<label>Participation | Participación*:</label>
      <select value={values.participation} onChange={set("participation")}>
        <option value=""> </option>
        {PARTICIPATION.map((c) => (
          <option key={c}>{c}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

I'm really, really clueless and would appreciate any insights about how to combine these two. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Have you considered using a form framework like Formik https://formik.org/. This will handle a lot of the complexity for you and make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Selector = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        participation: "",
        email: ""
    });

    const PARTICIPATION = [
        "Yes, I would like to participate in this activity.",
        "Sí, me gustaría participar en esta actividad.",
        ""
    ];

    return (
        <select value={values.participation} onChange={(event) => setValues({ ...values, participation: event.target.value })}>
            <option value=""> </option>
            {PARTICIPATION.map((c) => (
                <option value={c} key={c}>{c}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    )
}

export default Selector;
```